# Create index for lower case of a to z characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a database column which allow us to store lower case a to z characters and 'Space'. How we can create an index with more specific expressions.

We are need of this specific index to improve the 'Order by' clause performance issue.

The performance problem here is, when we do 'Order by' for large number of table column it creates problem. If the order by column is date or integer then it is faster but not for varchar type column.

We want to make the query faster by add specific index to the varchar column or make another decision

Comment: Have you tried creating an actual [INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html) on the column?

Comment: Yes I have tried. Still it takes 5000 milliseconds to return the result. I have tried with lower(column) index which help us to reduce 2500. So will try to get any specific index is possible to create. like a to z characters and 'Space character' alone

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest to take a look to this page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-expressional.html

Second, is the order by on the field, or on the expression? I mean, if your order by is:

```
ORDER BY col1
```

You just need to index like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_col1 ON yourtable (col1);
```

If your ORDER BY is:

```
ORDER BY lower(col1)
```

Then:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_lower_col1_table ON yourtable (lower(col1));
```

Anyway, to improve your question, I suggest to:

- Show your query
- Show execution plan retrived with EXPLAIN ANALYZE
- Show your table and indexes